# Golang do an async task without awaiting

Tags: go

Some pseudocode describing my problem:

1. Fetch a product from database a `FoodProduct`
2. check if isExpired() `FoodProduct.DueDate.Before(time.Now())`
3. `if isExpired()` then start **async** task to update the status of the FoodProduct in database as expired: `FoodProduct.updateStatus("expired")`

   [`if isExpired()=false` just skip to step 4.]
4. return `FoodProduct` to client via http without awaiting for answer from step 3

I know go has goroutines, mutex and many other goodies. If I don't care about the result of async operation what option should I use?

Comment: This question doesn't really make any sense - goroutines are the only method of running code asynchronously in Go. Mutexes et al are methods of synchronizing goroutines. If you don't explicitly synchronize them, they run asynchronously, and there is no such thing as "await" in Go.

Comment: @Adrian but "How to do something asynchronously without awaiting in golang" makes sense, and in context "I know go has goroutines, mutex, and many other goodies" is easily understandable as "I know Go has a bunch of concurrency stuff, but I don't know enough about it to solve this problem."

Comment: But go does not have "a bunch of concurrency stuff". It has goroutines, full stop. All the rest is for synchronization, ie reducing concurrency.

Comment: @Adrian SO is for helping and leaving easy to find (google) Q&A, references for future developers, including ourselves in the future. If you have no positive contribution I would suggest to just get over it and carry on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just start the async task with the `go` keyword. It'll spin off in its own goroutine and your main line of execution doesn't have to care about it anymore.

```
product := fetchProduct()
if product.isExpired() {
        go product.updateStatus("expired")
}
// return as normal
```

Note that since `product.updateStatus` is almost certainly changing the state of that product, it's difficult to predict when it's safe to use that product again (aka when it's been updated in the underlying database layer)

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur true -- fixed.

Comment: Might want to use WaitGroup in case the code exits before the update is done